# Have replicate function in R return several vectors or matrix in R

Tags: r

I want to simulate some data and return the different estimates of Beta 1 and Beta 2. I want to use replicate or similar function as lappy, sapply.

```
beta = matrix(data = rep(NA, 200), ncol = 2)

colnames(beta) = c("Beta 1", "Beta 2")

beta = replicate (100,{

  x = matrix(data = rep(NA, 300), ncol = 3)

  colnames(x) = c("y", "x1", "x2")

  x$y = rnorm(100,2,4)

  x$x1 = rnorm(100, 4,6)

  x$x2 = rnorm(100,  5,7)

  lm = lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = x)

  coef(lm)[2]  ; coef(lm)[3]  
})
```

Above only returns 100 replicates of one beta

Comment: `return(coef(lm)[2:3])` or `return(coef(lm))` ?

Comment: Yes - an expression or function can only return one object.  You need to group the two desired results into a vector.

Answer (score 2):

```
    beta = replicate (100,{
                      x = matrix(data = rep(NA, 300), ncol = 3)
                      colnames(x) = c("y", "x1", "x2")
                      x = data.frame(y=rnorm(100,2,4),
                                     x1=rnorm(100, 4,6),
                                     x2=rnorm(100, 5,7))
                      lm = lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = x)

                     beta=c(Beta1=coef(lm)[2],Beta2=coef(lm)[3])

                      })
                    beta=t(beta)
```

Comment: c(Beta1=coef(lm)[2], Beta2=coef(lm)[3]) is okay.

Comment: Thanks, can I somehow save beta as a matrix with 2 columns directly?

Answer (score 0):

use `sapply`:

```
res <- sapply(1:100, function(i){
  x = matrix(data = rep(NA, 300), ncol = 3)
  colnames(x) = c("y", "x1", "x2")
  x$y = rnorm(100,2,4)
  x$x1 = rnorm(100, 4,6)
  x$x2 = rnorm(100,  5,7)
  lm = lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = x)

  return(c(coef(lm)[2], coef(lm)[3]))
})

head(t(res))
#               x1           x2
# [1,]  0.01293551 -0.002520876
# [2,]  0.00294546 -0.034689928
# [3,]  0.05614309  0.049577728
# [4,] -0.02323345 -0.025082705
# [5,] -0.01016728  0.023558755
# [6,] -0.05317357  0.024496896
```

Comment: You don't use `i` within the function, so you might as well use `replicate`, as with @David's answer.